# Google Lens AR - Orbit Book Covers

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

Orbit Books has started creating AR book covers using google lens.  For an example, open up Lens and look at this image:  https://www.hachettebookgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/9780316368865-1.jpg?fit=436%2C675

I've been trying to figure out how it was done, but I can't find anything.  Sure, I can create a custom app that finds the image and overlays an AR environment on it, but I can't find any documentation on how to integrate within Google Lens itself.

Has anyone seen this before or know of the steps to, for example, add a similar experience to my own books.  (I assume it's a closed system since they wouldn't want anyone creating custom triggers on anything.)

Any advice would be great.  I have a group of authors that would love to add a similar experience to their books.

Comment: Are you sure this feature still works - could you share the OS (iOS, Android), device, exact Google app you are using if it works for you?

Comment: It definitely works for me.  Using a pixel 6 XL pro with the latest version of google lens.

Comment: Here is a video of it in action.  https://youtube.com/shorts/_zTLWguQKEo

Comment: That's really strange - the exact same approach does not detect for me on pixel 4. I'll try to investigate why (which is separate from your original issue).